# Add JSON Object to array

Tags: json, groovy

After first system call fails, i am getting this json.

```
{
    "header": {
        "msgCode": "400",
        "message": "Call failed!"
    },
    "body": {
        "success": false,
        "error_list": [
            
        ]
    }
}
```

After every next system call fails, i am getting receipt_code, which i have to append to above json.

```
{
    "header": {
        "msgCode": "400",
        "message": "Call failed!"
    },
    "body": {
        "success": false,
        "error_list": [
            {
                "errors": [
                    {
                      "message": "Invalid receipt code!"
                    }
                ],
                "receipt_code": "A-11277809" //here is receipt_code

            }
    ]
}
```

}

for all next calls if fail, then keep on appending this.

```
{
    "header": {
        "msgCode": "400",
        "message": "Call failed!"
    },
    "body": {
        "success": false,
        "error_list": [
            {
                "errors": [
                    {
                      "message": "Invalid receipt code!"
                    }
                ],
                "receipt_code": "11111"
            },
 {
                "errors": [
                    {
                      "message": "Invalid receipt code!"
                    }
                ],
                "receipt_code": "1222"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how can this be done by Groovy, any help
Here is my code

```
if(success!="true")
{
def receipt_code=receiptList[receiptFlag].receipt_code;
def error_list = []
def error ={
            "errors": [
                {
                  "message": "Invalid receipt code!"
                }
            ],
            "receipt_code": receipt_code //here is receipt_code

        }
             
error_list.push(error)
error_list = JSON.stringify(error_list)

msg.put("error_list",error_list);
}
```

I am not able to add using above code

Comment: What have you tried?  Assuming you have converted these into data structures, it should be an easy task.

Comment: @TimRoberts, added my code

Comment: Why you are not able? Any error message?

Comment: Unexpected input: ':' @ line 3, column 21.
               "errors": [

Comment: It looks like `msg` is not a local variable.  Is it the case that you are inadvertently reusing an instance that you should be a new instance for each error?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, i can ignore msg. thats not the issue, msg is my my system variable.

Comment: @kekukeku "i can ignore msg. thats not the issue" - It might be good to remove the irrelevant stuff from the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Using JsonSlurper**

```
import groovy.json.*

String text = """
{
    "header": {
        "msgCode": "400",
        "message": "Call failed!"
    },
    "body": {
        "success": false,
        "error_list": [
            
        ]
    }
}
"""

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)

errors = [
    ['errors': [['message': 'hi']], 'code': 100],
    ['errors': [['message': 'hello']], 'code': 200]
]

for (err in errors)
    json.body.error_list << err
    
println JsonOutput.toJson(json)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "header": {
        "msgCode": "400",
        "message": "Call failed!"
    },
    "body": {
        "success": false,
        "error_list": [
            {
                "errors": [
                    {
                        "message": "hi"
                    }
                ],
                "code": 100
            },
            {
                "errors": [
                    {
                        "message": "hello"
                    }
                ],
                "code": 200
            }
        ]
    }
}
```